# Svn revert trunk from tag

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Here is my scenario

Common directory structure

```
 branches 
 tags 
 trunk
```

After doing an initial import to a trunk, i also do a tag `/repo/tags/v1.0` (using head on trunk)

Let say i working on trunk and do tons of commit, and then i realize i mess up the trunk.

Instead of using `svn revert`, I plan to revert the trunk to its initial status like in `/tags/v1.0`

Is there a way to revert `trunk` using `tags`?

I have been trying (using tortoise svn) to merge trunk and tags using reverse merge but up to no avail.

Is this possible?

Any suggestion how to revert trunk to its stable version like in `/tags.v1.0` is appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe it's possible without merging/reverting:

1. Remove /trunk (just in case make a backup copy of it)
2. Move project/tags/tag.v1.0 to project/tag.v1.0
3. Rename project/tag.v1.0 to project/trunk

Comment: And btw, if you expect your changes can mess up trunk - create a feature branch.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `tags` to revert, except as a point of reference. Use `tags` to figure out what revision you need to revert to (`svn log  URL_TO_tags/v1.0 --stop-on-copy`), then in a working copy checked out from `trunk`, perform a reverse merge of `trunk` using a range of `HEAD:X` where `X` is the revision you made the tag at. (i.e. `svn merge -r HEAD:X`)

Comment: i thought by using `tag` i can recreate back the state of project i want

Comment: You don't need a tag to do that (a tag is just a copy, nothing more). You *can* use it, but it'll make your repository history uglier.

Comment: how to do it...i want to know

Comment: I described how in my answer.